# Reveal JS making only part of the screen respond to swipe gesture

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-plugins, touchscreen

I'm looking to make a mock-up html app. I have been using reveal JS and my own jquery to make the bulk of it, but i need only part of the page to be "sensitive" to the swipe gestures. Does anyone know of a way to make only part of the screen area sensitive?

Thanks

Comment: I am using this framework http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/

Answer (score 0):

Well put an HTML element there covering the desired area and bind the swipe event to it.

For more of a concept you should try something and comeback with a code example if no success.